# Make Animations Smoother in HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a logo of an iceberg, which I am trying to simulate a floating animation with by increasing and decreasing the top margin. I am using the following css for this:

```css
img {
  height: 60px;
  padding: 5px;
  -webkit-animation: logofloat 1s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  -moz-animation: logofloat 1s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  animation: logofloat 1s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes logofloat {
from {
  margin-top: 0px; margin-top: 5px;
}
to {
  margin-top: 5px;  margin-top: 10px;
}
}
```

Here is what that currently looks like: https://gyazo.com/bbd8991a3e9a42148bb7677b85d0db3d

The animation is a bit choppy, is there anything that I can do to make it smoother?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `transform: translateY` instead of `margin`, so the animation will take benefit of the `GPU` and use `will-change: transform` so the browser  [knows in advance](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/w/will-change/) what properties are going to change.

```css
img {
  height: 100px;
  will-change: transform;
  animation: logofloat 1s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes logofloat {
   from {
       transform: translateY(0);
   }
   to {
       transform: translateY(10px);
   }
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJ3pb.jpg" />
```

Finally, vendor prefixes are no longer necessary unless you need  to  support really old browser versions.